# My app was accepted with "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"warning

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I got this e-mail from Apple but my app was not rejected. If I release this version, will push notification be available to my users? Can I test it? If I have to resubmit, is there a way to not increment my app's version? Everything is working fine in the development environment and I already have everything set to the production environment as well (app id, certificate, provision profile, all of them using push notification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that warning is correct, push notifications won't work for your app in production.

The way to test your app with the production APNS environment is to build your App with an AdHoc provisioning profile, which will cause it to use the production push environment. This will allow your server to use the production certificate to send notification to the production APNS server.

Of course, even if it works, you still have to check your actual production provisioning profile, to see whether it contains the `<aps-environment>` with `Distribution` value.

Comment: Thanks @Eran. What about the version? Can I reject my binary even with my app accepted (I didn't release it)

Comment: @balboa I don't know about that, sorry.

Comment: the answer is yes (at least before releasing)

Answer (score 0):

Recreate your Distribution provisioning profile and build my application with it. This change will fix the issue of Missing Push Notification Entitlements

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above warning by following steps

Step 1:Go to '**Capabilities**' Tab

Step 2:Select '**Background Modes**' section and unchecked '**Remote notifications**' [image]